# How to revoke given permission in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, w3c

One of the new APIs made available to developers is [Geolocation API](http://www.thoughtresults.com/geolocation-api). As it's been defined in Specification, any browser should take the express permission of the user when revealing his/her geographic position to the surfed website. However, it's also been said that user can revoke that given permission at any time. I searched almost everywhere in Chrome and Firefox and I didn't find any place to revoke given permissions. Does anyone know how should I do that? (This is also the case in [Contacts API](http://www.thoughtresults.com/contacts-api))

Answer (score 39, accepted):

chrome://settings/content has a section that allows you to revoke location permissions.

Comment: Great, thank you. It's been said that revocation process should be easy. This was kind of less intuitive than being considered easy.

Comment: Note that you don't have to get there via the url, it's just a convenient shortcut

Answer (score 10):

For Firefox: Right-click the page, "View Page Info", there go to the "Permissions" tab. The entry you are interested in is "Share Location".

**Edit** (2016-05-12): In current Firefox versions you can also click the info icon next to the location bar. This will show you all the special permissions you've granted the current page and will allow changing them.

This approach works in Chrome as well, there you click the document icon next to the site name. Difference is that Chrome will show you a list of all permissions, not just the ones you've granted already.

Comment: Still far from being easily accessible. Thank you.

Comment: @Saeed: Not sure, how much easier do you want to have it? That's the page summarizing everything you allowed that webpage to do.

Comment: Page info shows something in Chrome, shows something else in Firefox. There is no page info in IE and ..., to be intuitive means that you gotta go to tools menu, click options, there should be a tab called security. It's simpler. :)

Answer (score 1):

In **Android Chromium** (default Android browser; usually called "Browser" or "Internet") you must go to *Settings > Privacy > Remove private date, check Location access and click OK*.

In **Android Chrome** open Menu (HW button or top-right button) and go to *Settings > Advanced > Content settings > Website settings and uncheck Location access* under each website you want to reset the settings.

For **Android Firefox** go to the page with location access and *long press the URL* bar (it have to be highlighted while you press it). In popup menu choose *Edit site settings, check the Share location and click Clear*.

And in **Android Opera** you must delete all web data (*Menu > Settings > Clear Browsing data > Clear Cookies and Data*).

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you can just click the document that is to the left of the URL in the address bar and change all your different privacy settings, including geo tag, from there.

Answer (score 0):

In **Chrome**, the most straight-forward way to manage location settings for a site is to:

1. Enter the site
2. Click the *crosshair symbol* (position indicator, ⌖) that is second on the right:

[image: Chrome address bar with location icon]

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, on the address bar there will be a padlock or a info button. Click on it and it will open a popup with option of drop down next to Location. If location service is already given permission then Block option will be available to revoke it.